# When does AngularJS propagate model changes to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In AngularJS, you can watch for model changes using `$watch`.  So, if I write something like:

```
$scope.$watch('model', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    // React to the change...
});
```

...then I can be notified when the model `$scope.model` changes and do something.

However, if that `model` is bound to an AngularJS view (i.e. `model.name` is bound to the name of a user on an HTML page), when the `$watch` callback fires, this change will not yet have been propagated to the DOM.

My question is: when does AngularJS propagate a model change to the DOM, and how can I listen for that event?

**EDIT**

The use case is making an absolutely positioned scroller that has a variable sized fixed header and scrolling content (see this Plunk to get an idea: http://plnkr.co/edit/LdYl7e7GYhdGiF3NQ0Bv)

This is what the directive looks like right now:

```
.directive('psScroller', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            'model': '=ngModel'
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            var _this = this;
            var _headerElement;
            var _contentElement;

            $scope.resize = function () {
                if (!_headerElement || !_contentElement) return;
                $timeout(function() {
                    _contentElement.css('top', _headerElement.height())
                });
            };

            this.setHeaderElement = function (headerElement) {
                _headerElement = headerElement;
                _headerElement.on('keydown', $scope.resize);
            };

            this.setContentElement = function (contentElement) {
                _contentElement = contentElement;
            };
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.$watch('model', function () {
                scope.resize();
            }, true);
        },
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
    };
});
```

So the idea is that I adjust the content height to match the header height.

Comment: what is the use case please ?

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal I have a DOM element `a` that depends on the size of element `b` which contains model text. I can't resize `a` until I know how tall `b` is with the new text.

Comment: I don't think there's an event that's fired when the DOM is updated from ngModel. You can view the AngularJs event loop [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime) here. Notice DOM update happens at the end. I would suggest creating a directive for your use case.

Comment: @CuongVo I'm not sure how I'd solve the problem with that? I'd still need to monitor changes in the model and thus need to use `$watch`... unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some mock data and a simple template of what you're trying to do? I don't quite get what `a` does in the use case and why it wouldn't also update its size when the model changes if both `a` and `b` depend on the same model.

Comment: @CuongVo I've posted a Plunk of the HTML/CSS and the code for my directive as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Angular directives are responsible for reflecting model changes in the DOM. They register watch listeners on model elements and change the DOM when these watch listeners are invoked. So when you are watching the same model properties as the directives, your watch listener may be invoked before the watch listener registered by the respective directive, so the DOM has not yet been changed.

You can use either a timeout or `$scope.$evalAsync()` in your watch listener to defer the execution of your code and wait until the DOM has been changed. How both solutions differ is for instance explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19889541/302793) to a related question.